# How does one use pytest monkeypatch to patch a class

Tags: python, class, pytest, monkeypatching

I would like to use [pytest monkeypatch][1] to mock a class which is imported
into a separate module.  Is this actually possible, and if so how does one do it?  It seems like I have not seen an example for this exact situation.  Suppose you have app with and imported class A in something.py

```py
from something import A #Class is imported

class B :
  def __init__(self) :
   self.instance = A() #class instance is created

  def f(self, value) :
    return self.instance.g(value)
```

inside my test.py I want to mock A inside B

```py
from something import B

#this is where I would mock A such that
def mock_A :
  def g(self, value) :
    return 2*value

#Then I would call B
c = B()
print(c.g(2)) #would be 4

I see how monkeypatch can be used to patch instances of classes, but how is it done for classes that have not yet been instantiated?  Is it possible?  Thanks!

  [1]: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tested this, works for me:

```
def test_thing(monkeypatch):
    def patched_g(self, value):
        return value * 2

    monkeypatch.setattr(A, 'g', patched_g)
    b = B()
    assert b.f(2) == 4
```

Comment: I do not see why this is the approved answer. Of course it works, but do you then need do `monkeypath` for every attribute? It would be simpler to create a mock class containing the methods needed and use the full class with one call to monkeypatch instead of several. Wouldn't it?

Comment: Sometimes you only need to monkeypatch a method or two (for example, if they make API calls that you want to mock).

Comment: Classic. There's 1 answer. It works. But why is it approved? Even if another answer was provided using `unittest.mock` that's not in the terms of the question. We're trying to work with `pytest. monkeypatch` here. There's enough `unittest.mock` answers already.